# why this regex doesn't match any of these strings?

Tags: c#, regex

why this regex doesn't match any of the following strings?

```
string regx = "<td\\s+class=\"inline-rating-sm\"\\s+data-ci=\"\\d + \">\\s+(\\d+)</td>";
```

Test strings:

```
<td class="inline-rating-sm" data-ci="943"> (150)</td>
<td class="inline-rating-sm" data-ci="922"> (66)</td>
```

Comment: i'd consider a dom parsing library.

Comment: Don't wrote "a regex to match strings". The way to write a regex is basically to take the string to match, escape everything in it that's special regex symbols, and then replace any variable contents (like the numbers here) by expressions. I also strongly advice using some editor that supports regex highlighting. There are plenty of regex testers online that can do that.

Comment: More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/397817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
\"\\d + \">
```

matches a `"` explicitly, then any digit, then a space one or more times, then another space, then `">` explicitly. I think you want

```
\"\\d+\">
```

Additionally you're not escaping the `()` parentheses, which mean a capture group in regex, or the `/` in `</td>`.

Also you might want to use the verbatim modifier `@`.

```
var regx = @"<td\s+class=""inline-rating-sm""\s+data-ci=""\d+"">\s+\(\d+\)<\/td>";
```

It's more readable without constant `\\` escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Because following syntax is *special* in regex: `(...)`, meaning [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

If you want to match brackets literally, you need to escape them: `\\(` and `\\)` (I used double slash, first to escape the other slash, so it escapes bracket in regex :) ).

You also need to escape `/` in `</td>`, below I present pattern after few corrections.

You need to modify your pattern to: `<td\s+class="inline-rating-sm"\s+data-ci="\d*">\s+\(\d+\)<\/td>` (remember to escape slashes in C# :) ).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NaGxqz/1)

Comment: sorry, didn't work.

Comment: @medoampir See update :)

Answer (score -1):

As an answer to the underlying problem, in many circumstances an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression to match them is a better option, and can be simpler and more robust.

For example, I added the HtmlAgilityPack to a new project with "Tools" -> "NuGet Package Manager" -> "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." and used this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string h = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<table class=""table"">
<tr><th scope=""row"">Not this</th><td>123</td></tr>
<tr><th scope=""row"">Or this</th><td>456</td></tr>
<tr><td class=""inline-rating-sm"" data-ci=""943""> (150)</td><td class=""inline-rating-sm"" data-ci=""922""> (66)</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>";

    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(h);

    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(@"//table[@class='table']");
    var cells = table.SelectNodes(@".//td[@class='inline-rating-sm' and @data-ci]");

    // do something with the cells...
    foreach (var cell in cells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cell.GetAttributeValue("data-ci", "") + " " + cell.InnerText.Trim());

    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

to output:

> 943 (150)
>   922 (66)